# What's the best way to get a date from a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, mapping

Not sure how to go about it but what would be the easiest way to map the following values and return a date in output?

```
values = [2009, 11, 1, 2, 6, 9, 19, 0]
map = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day Of Week', 'Day', 'Hr', 'Min', 'Sec', 'MSec']
output = '2 NOV 2009 06:09:19 UTC'
```

EDIT:

output preferably a datetime obj and not string. Sorry for the confusion
List will always be length of 8 values. and always mapped to the `map` index order. So `map` and `values` will always be 8 and `map[0]` should be `values[0]`

Comment: Do you want the output to be a datetime object or just a string type? Also, how many different "values" do you have?

Comment: Let me add more to the question :) @S4rt-H4K hope it helps

Comment: side note: don't redefine the built-in `map`! this can give you hard-to-debug errors if you need to use map somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply unpack the appropriate values from the "values" list into datetime.datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

values = [2009, 11, 1, 2, 6, 9, 19, 0]

dtobj = datetime(*values[:2], *values[3:], tzinfo=timezone.utc)

output = dtobj.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z').lstrip('0')
# '2 Nov 2009 06:09:19 UTC'
```

Comment: this is awesome. Thank you for it. I don't fully understand what's happening with the unpack but Google will help me :) Thank you for this.

Comment: @MarcoFernandes: glad I could help. Basically, the `*` (in front of a sequence) will return the sequence's individual members. You can imagine it as e.g. `a, b = *[0, 1]` will give `a == 0; b == 1`. That's called *unpacking*.

Comment: I've been playing around with unpacking since you mentioned it. Not sure how I never came across this method :)

Comment: @MarcoFernandes: the syntax in my comment is actually invalid, I hope you noticed ^^ Was just for illustration purpose.